# Change of coordinates on a manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading introduction to smooth manifolds by John M. Lee. I don't understand a part of change of coordinates.

[image]

What are $(x^i)$ and $\tilde{x}^i$. It says here that these are "coordinate functions". What are coordinate functions? In this post [What is a coordinate function $x^i$ of a manifold, given a chart $(U,x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720328/what-is-a-coordinate-function-xi-of-a-manifold-given-a-chart-u-x) it says that $i$-th coordinate function output $i$-th coordinate of point in $R^n$. Is it true? Is $x=(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ and $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}(x)=\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$?. If yes (but I don't think so because these are treated like number, elements from $R^n$, not functions just by looking at the domain of the map) then I can't understand following picture.

[image]

The first $n$ coordinates of $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}(x^1,x^2,...,x^n,v^1,v^2,...,v^n)=(\tilde{x}^1(x),\tilde{x}^2(x),...,\tilde{x}^n(x),...)=(\tilde{x}^1(x^1,x^2,...,x^n),\tilde{x}^2(x^1,x^2,...,x^n),...,\tilde{x}^n(x^1,x^2,...,x^n),...)$

But now these $x^i$ are numbers, elements of $R^n$, not functions. I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: The term coordinate function is defined by the author on page 4 in the book you are reading (start of the section titled "Coordinate Charts").

Comment: Not really. It says that $\varphi$ is a (local) coordinate map (I assume map=function), but In the picture I sent it is written: "denote coordinate functions of $\varphi$ as $x^i$". So maybe coordinates functions of $\varphi$ are coordinate funtions, but then If $x=(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ it make no sense to me, they are treated as functions and numbers at the same time. Maybe $x$ is not equal to (x^1,x^2,...,x^n) but it is on the second picture I sent.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4706005.